# "Cannot find symbol" Error in Java. Something with my ArrayList is off

Tags: java

```
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
class UNIT5 extends ArrayList
{public static void main(String args[])
 {
 String sentence="Extremely";
 ArrayList<String> words= new ArrayList<String>();
 System.out.println(sentence);
 }
}
```

So this was my code for Java and when I attempt to compile it, the compiler tells me that all of the ArrayList or capital Array A's are symbols that can't be found.

Comment: Try: `import java.util.Arrays`

Comment: Did you `import java.util.ArrayList`?

Comment: you are missing the generic parameters. Either you extend from ArrayList<Something> or you create a class Unit5<T>

Comment: @DanieL. That is not the cause of his compile problem but yes, it would be better for him to do that. Actually, for what we can see so far there is no need to extending ArrayList.

Comment: "import java.util.ArrayList" Did the trick.

Comment: @Claudio For sure, just no need to re-hash the previous comments ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You are using ArrayList without importing it. So import it like:

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
```

Note aside, Your extension ArrayList doesn't makes sense. Also your static import as you are not using it, so you should get rid of those. Also ArrayList deals with Generics which your code doesn't.

Comment: THANK YOU! I tried import java.util.ArrayList before but it wasn't working then either. The way my teacher made it sound was that ArrayList was a sort of class that I needed to use so I was very confused.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `ArrayList`

```
import java.util.ArrayList
```